# Javascript function call from ASP .NET Hyperlink NavigateURL property

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ASP table that I create dynamically on the page load event.  In that event, I populate the ASP table with titles and then a ASP .NET Hyperlink control that points to a .ashx page to serve up a file for the client to download.

For particular files (image files), I'd like to kick off a javascript function to open a new window with that file displayed in it.  I have all the code to do this, but I can't get my Javascript function to work in the hyperlink NavigateURL property.  I'm very new to Javascript, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Can I do what I'm trying to?  Can I not use the table control?

ASP code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim iWineID As Integer

    If Not Integer.TryParse(Request.Params("WineID"), iWineID) Then Throw New InvalidOperationException("Invalid request")
    Me.lblWineName.Text = Utils.GetWineName(iWineID)
    Dim dtDocs As New dsDocs.docsDataTable

    Using taDocs As New dsDocsTableAdapters.docsTableAdapter
        dtDocs = taDocs.GetDataByProdIDOrWineID((Utils.GetProducerIDByWineID(iWineID)), True, iWineID)
    End Using

    If dtDocs.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Me.lblDocsFound.Text = "No documents available for this wine."
    Else
        Me.NumberDocs(dtDocs)

        For Each drDoc As dsDocs.docsRow In dtDocs
            Dim myRow As New TableRow
            Dim myTitleCell As New TableCell
            Dim myDLCell As New TableCell
            Dim myHL As New HyperLink
            Select Case drDoc.doc_type_id
                'window.open('preview.aspx?WineID=' + nWineID', 'height=' + nWindowHeight + ',width=' + nWindowWidth + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=' + bScrollbars + ',resizable=' + bScrollbars + ',titlebar=no');
                Case Constants.DocType.BottleShot, Constants.DocType.Label, Constants.DocType.Logo
                    myHL.NavigateUrl = "javascript:OpenPrev('" & drDoc.doc_id & "');return false;" '"javascript:window.open('~/Home/docpreview.aspx?DocID=" & drDoc.doc_id '& "','_blank', 'height=600, width=600,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,titlebar=no'"
                    '"~/Home/docpreview.aspx?DocID=" & drDoc.doc_id
                    myHL.Text = "View"
                Case Else
                    myHL.NavigateUrl = "~/Home/docs.ashx?DocID=" & drDoc.doc_id
                    myHL.Text = "Download"
            End Select

            myTitleCell.Text = StrConv(drDoc.doc_type_name, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            myDLCell.Controls.Add(myHL)
            myRow.Cells.Add(myTitleCell)
            myRow.Cells.Add(myDLCell)
            Me.tableDocs.Rows.Add(myRow)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Javascript

```
function OpenPrev(DocID){

var objWin
var myURL

alert("GO!");
myURL='~/Home/docpreview.aspx?DocID=' + DocID;
objWin=window.open(myURL, 'Doc View', 'width=600,height=600,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no');
}
```

Comment: Without digging too deep, just one quick thing: Javascript doesn't understand the concept of the `~` in the URL - that's a .NET concept, available in server code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JoeEnos - That's definitely part of it. Try using something like 'http://www.google.com' as `myURL` and see. what happens.

And view the source of the HTML page and see what the generated hyperlinks look like. The `href` attribute will probably look wrong.

Comment: I got this working by trying another url.  I tried it again, and it worked.  I was using Firefox at work, and then I used Chrome and it worked no problem - but no dice on firefox.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Can you view the source in Chrome and Firefox and post it so we can all take a look and figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to first resolve the URL.

Try changing any place where you set the NavigateURL like:

```
myHL.NavigateUrl = "~/Home/docs.ashx?DocID=" & drDoc.doc_id
```

To:

```
myHL.NavigateUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "Home/docs.ashx?DocID=" & drDoc.doc_id
```